# How does jQuery handle the click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new to jQuery and cannot get a selector to work using the id of the element. The code below works:

```
$(function() {  
  /* $("#ShowBox").onclick = ShowAccessible;  */  
  document.getElementById("ShowBox").onclick = ShowAccessible;  
  /* $(".searchcheck").click = ShowAccessible; */  
});

function ShowAccessible() {  
  $("tr.hide").fadeOut();  
}
```

However, neither of the two commented out lines work i.e. they do not apply the click event to a checkbox named "ShowBox" with a class of "searchcheck".  Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JQuery uses functions rather than properties to set the handlers.

```
$("#ShowBox").click(ShowAccessible);
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. I misread the tutorial which has an example of this.

Answer (score 8):

there is no onclick property for a jQuery object; when you use `$([selector])`, a jQuery object is returned, not an element.

Use either

```
.click(function () { ...}); // can be an anonymous function or named function
```

or

```
.bind('click', function() { ... }); // can be an anonymous function or named function
```

like so

```
$("#ShowBox").click(ShowAccessible);
$("#ShowBox").bind('click', ShowAccessible);
```

Comment: Oops, typo - this does not work either  
<pre>
$("#ShowAccessible").click = ShowAccessible;
</pre>

Answer (score 0):

if you really had to do it with an assignment , i think

$("#ShowBox")[0].onclick = ShowAccessible;

would work.